# counter_cache for a virtual attribute in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

Is it possible to create a counter cache for a virtual attribute in Rails?

**Background:** I have Posts that get voted on, and have a counter_cache for votes (votes_count) in the Post database.

**Objective:** I have a "vote score" I calculate as a virtual attribute using the current votes_count along with other variables, is there a way to store this "vote score" as a cached value in my Post database as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just add an attribute called "vote_score" and store it. If you're looking for a "magic" way to do this - there is none.

If you simply don't want to run the calculation everytime the method is called, memoize the result.

```
def vote_score
  @vote_score ||= heavy_calculation(votes_count)
end
```

Or, via [ActiveSupport::Memoizable](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Memoizable/memoize):

```
def vote_score
  heavy_calculation(votes_count)
end
memoize :vote_score
```